# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $x,y \in G$. Show that $x(Hy)=(xH)y.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $x,y \in G$. Show that $x(Hy)=(xH)y.$

I have that $Hy=\{hy \mid h \in H\}$ so wouldn't $x(Hy)=\{x hy \mid h \in H\}$? If so there doesn't seem to be much to be shown since if this holds I suppose that $(xH)y=\{x h y \mid h \in H\}$ would also hold and these two are clearly the same sets? Am I misinterpreting the set $x(Hy)$? Should this be $\{xhy \mid h \in H, y \in G\}$ for fixed $y$?

Comment: Indeed, there is not much to be shown. Keep in mind that when you write $x(hy)$ as $xhy$, you are implicitly using the associativity of the group operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct.

---

This can be done in a few lines:

$$\begin{align}
x(Hy)&=\{xh'\mid h'\in Hy\}\\
&=\{x(hy)\mid h\in H\}\\
&=\{(xh)y\mid h\in H\}\\
&=\{h''y\mid h''\in xH\}\\
&=(xH)y.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You are entirely correct; there isn't much to be shown, and you've shown it.

Comment: I feel like this ought to be a comment.

Comment: @Shaun I feel like there simply isn't much to be said, and I've said it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If $w\in x(Hy),$ then for some $v\in Hy,$ $w=xv.$ Since $v\in Hy,$ for some $h\in H,$ $v=hy.$ So $w = xhy.$ So for some $u\in xH,$ $w=uy.$ Thus $w\in (xH)y.$

Therefore $x(Hy)\subseteq (xH)y.$

The inclusion in the other direction can be shown in the same way.